# Play key opening iTunes even if Spotify is currently selected

Tags: itunes, keyboard, music

I normally use spotify for music, but I go from time to time to iTunes to listen to some Podcasts.

Sometimes I have both applications opened, and when I want to stop one, I select the application and (<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> until finding the app) and I hit <kbd>space</kbd> which stops playing it.

The thing is that I developed that habit because of the `play/pause` key wasn't working, and was only stopping iTunes if it was opened.

I would like the `play/pause` key (and all music related keys) to work on the app that I selected last, is that possible or configurable?

I am using a Macbook Pro with Touch Bar (`Mojave 10.14.1`)

Comment: are you saying that Spotify is not reacting to the `play/pause` keys ? or to stop iTunes from opening.

Comment: When iTunes is also opened

Comment: right now the play key is linked to iTunes only, not to your top window. First we need to find a way to unlink iTunes from it when iTunes is in background and Spotify is the active window. Tough one !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this for you.

> [Mac Media Key Forwarder](http://milgra.com/mac-media-key-forwarder.html)
>
> Forwards media keys to iTunes or Spotify directly.
>
> You can prioritize which app you would like to control or you can go
>   with the default behavior which controls the running app. The app
>   runs in the menu bar.

It has some limitations.

It might not work on Mojave till (if) the developer fixes it.